# Need simple modification for Javascript Cookie notice wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect, cookies

I followed a [tutorial](https://www.wplogout.com/add-cookie-notice-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/) to create cookie notice popup for my wordpress site, it works as expected, I'm not good at javascript, so I want after user click on `X` button and accept cookies, to be automatically redirected to the same page with `?ok=3` query

`<script>cookieLaw={dId:"cookie-law-div",bId:"cookie-law-button",iId:"cookie-law-item",show:function(e){if(localStorage.getItem(cookieLaw.iId))return!1;var o=document.createElement("div"),i=document.createElement("p"),t=document.createElement("button");i.innerHTML=e.msg,t.id=cookieLaw.bId,t.innerHTML=e.ok,o.id=cookieLaw.dId,o.appendChild(t),o.appendChild(i),document.body.insertBefore(o,document.body.lastChild),t.addEventListener("click",cookieLaw.hide,!1)},hide:function(){document.getElementById(cookieLaw.dId).outerHTML="",localStorage.setItem(cookieLaw.iId,"1")}},cookieLaw.show({msg:"We use cookies to give you the best possible experience. By continuing to visit our website, you agree to the use of cookies as described in our <a href='#'>Cookie Policy</a>",ok:"x"});</script>`

Comment: What's wrong with my question, instead of helping me fixing the problem, I found some people give me negative rating, if you don't know the answer it's ok, but why this negative rating ?!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I felt bad that some people instead of helping me fix my issue, they decide to give me negative rate. but I'll share the solution which fix my issue, in case other people facing the same issue, the problem wasn't in finding the JS code to navigate to a web page `location.href`, the problem was where should I add it in this minifyed code.

Anyways, the solution is:

adding `,location.href = window.location.href+"?ok=3";`

after `localStorage.setItem(cookieLaw.iId,"1"),`

and before `}},cookieLaw.show({`

so the final code will be:

`<script>cookieLaw={dId:"cookie-law-div",bId:"cookie-law-button",iId:"cookie-law-item",show:function(e){if(localStorage.getItem(cookieLaw.iId))return!1;var o=document.createElement("div"),i=document.createElement("p"),t=document.createElement("button");i.innerHTML=e.msg,t.id=cookieLaw.bId,t.innerHTML=e.ok,o.id=cookieLaw.dId,o.appendChild(t),o.appendChild(i),document.body.insertBefore(o,document.body.lastChild),t.addEventListener("click",cookieLaw.hide,!1)},hide:function(){document.getElementById(cookieLaw.dId).outerHTML="",localStorage.setItem(cookieLaw.iId,"1"),location.href = window.location.href+"?ok=3";}},cookieLaw.show({msg:"We use cookies to give you the best possible experience. By continuing to visit our website, you agree to the use of cookies as described in our <a href='#'>Cookie Policy</a>",ok:"x"});</script>`

Maybe the solution was easy, but as I mentioned, I'm good at javascript, specially that the code looks minifyed.